# How to convert Xmla file to Xml format

Tags: xml, ssas, msbi, xmla

I am working on ER diagram for a tabular model(SSAS), so converted my model to XMLA file, but my ER diagram tool is accepting only xml format files. So, I need info how to convert my xmla file to xml.

Answer (score 0):

**XMLA** files will be of the format **JSON**. You can easily convert **XMLA** files into **XML** files using python.

```
import json 
from json2xml import json2xml
with open('XMLA.xmla') as xmlafile: 
    data = json.load(xmlafile) 
print(json2xml.Json2xml(data).to_xml())
```

Comment: Hi @Vishnu, I am a beginner in Python, so I tried the above commands and it didn't work, are you sure it is working and this conversion works for xmla?

Comment: Hey, are you able to load .xmla file to Python using json.load() function?